# How to integrate GoogleSpellChecker with SpringMVC with ServletWrappingController

Tags: java, servlets, spring-mvc

Currently my application uses SpringMVC for all of my controller mappings.  I'm trying to implement a tinyMCE spellcheck and it includes a Servlet which I'm unsure how to properly integrate properly **without modifying this file itself**.  I want to avoid modification so that if we get a new version later we'll be ok.

The Servlet looks like...

```
public abstract class TinyMCESpellCheckerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TinyMCESpellCheckerServlet.class.getName());

    private static final String MAX_SUGGESTIONS_COUNT_PARAM = "maxSuggestionsCount";
    private static final String PRELOADED_LANGUAGES_PARAM = "preloadedLanguages";

    private static final String DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = "en";
    private static final String GET_METHOD_RESPONSE_ERROR = "This servlet expects a JSON encoded body, POSTed to this URL";

    private static String DEFAULT_PRELOADED_LANGUAGES = "en-us";

    private enum methods {
        checkWords, getSuggestions
    }

    private int maxSuggestionsCount = 25;


    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        super.init();
        preloadSpellcheckers();
        readMaxSuggestionsCount();
    }

    private void preloadSpellcheckers() throws ServletException {
        String preloaded = getServletConfig().getInitParameter(PRELOADED_LANGUAGES_PARAM);
        if (preloaded == null || preloaded.trim().length() == 0) {
            preloaded = DEFAULT_PRELOADED_LANGUAGES;
        }

        String[] preloadedLanguages = preloaded.split(";");
        for (String preloadedLanguage : preloadedLanguages) {
            try {
                preloadLanguageChecker(preloadedLanguage);
            } catch (SpellCheckException e) {
                //wrong servlet configuration
                throw new ServletException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    protected abstract void preloadLanguageChecker(String preloadedLanguage) throws SpellCheckException;

    /**
     * This method look for the already created SpellChecker object in the cache, if it is not present in the cache then
     * it try to load it and put newly created object in the cache. SpellChecker loading is quite expensive operation
     * to do it for every spell-checking request, so in-memory-caching here is almost a "MUST to have"
     *
     * @param lang the language code like "en" or "en-us"
     * @return instance of SpellChecker for particular implementation
     * @throws SpellCheckException if method failed to load the SpellChecker for lang (it happens if there is no
     *                             dictionaries for that language was found in the classpath
     */
    protected abstract Object getChecker(String lang) throws SpellCheckException;


    private void readMaxSuggestionsCount() throws ServletException {
        String suggestionsCountParam = getServletConfig().getInitParameter(MAX_SUGGESTIONS_COUNT_PARAM);
        if (suggestionsCountParam != null && suggestionsCountParam.trim().length() > 0) {
            try {
                maxSuggestionsCount = Integer.parseInt(suggestionsCountParam.trim());
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                //wrong servlet configuration, possibly a typo
                throw new ServletException(ex);
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * @see javax.servlet.Servlet#destroy()
     */
    public void destroy() {
        super.destroy();
        //remove unused objects from memory
        clearSpellcheckerCache();
    }

    protected abstract void clearSpellcheckerCache();


    /**
     * GET method is not supported
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        setResponeHeaders(response);
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        pw.println(GET_METHOD_RESPONSE_ERROR);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        setResponeHeaders(response);
        try {
            JSONObject jsonInput = readRequest(request);

            String methodName = jsonInput.optString("method");
            if (methodName == null || methodName.trim().equals("")) {
                throw new SpellCheckException("Wrong spellchecker-method-name:" + methodName);
            }

            JSONObject jsonOutput = new JSONObject("{'id':null,'result':[],'error':null}");
            switch (methods.valueOf(methodName.trim())) {
                case checkWords:
                    jsonOutput.put("result", checkWords(jsonInput.optJSONArray("params")));
                    break;
                case getSuggestions:
                    jsonOutput.put("result", getSuggestions(jsonInput.optJSONArray("params")));
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new SpellCheckException("Unimplemented spellchecker method {" + methodName + "}");
            }

            PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
            pw.println(jsonOutput.toString());

        } catch (SpellCheckException se) {
            logger.log(Level.WARNING, se.getMessage(), se);
            returnError(response, se.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.log(Level.WARNING, e.getMessage(), e);
            returnError(response, e.getMessage());
        }

        response.getWriter().flush();
    }
.....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `ServletWrappingController` ([javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/ServletWrappingController.html))

> Spring `Controller` implementation that wraps a servlet instance which it manages internally. Such a wrapped servlet is not known outside of this controller; its entire lifecycle is covered here (in contrast to `ServletForwardingController`).
>
> Useful to invoke an existing servlet via Spring's dispatching infrastructure, for example to apply Spring HandlerInterceptors to its requests.

Configure one of these in your Spring context, configuring it with your TinyMCE servlet class name, and map it using a `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping`.

`ServletForwardingController` is also useful, but slightly different.

Comment: Can you help with an example?  I'm struggling to understand exactly that this looks like when it's functional

Comment: @Webnet: The javadoc link has an example.

Comment: I've taken the documentation and tried to build a configuration off of that.  I'm getting an error but I'm having trouble determining what the cause is.  Can you take a look at the updated post and see if you can provide any guidance?

Comment: I've posted the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507763/getting-unknown-exception-when-implementing-servletwrappingcontroller since it's a separate issue.  You definitely pointed me in the right direction - thanks!