# Getting unknown exception when implementing ServletWrappingController

Tags: java, servlets, spring-mvc

I've been working on implementing the ServletWrappingController method and I'm having a few issues.  Here's my config...

```
<!-- Setup Spring ServletWrappers -->
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="/spellchecker/google-spellchecker.do">tinyMCESpellCheckerWrappingController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="tinyMCESpellCheckerWrappingController" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController">
    <property name="servletClass">
        <value>org.tinymce.spellchecker.TinyMCESpellCheckerServlet</value>
    </property>
    <property name="servletName">
        <value>doPost</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I'm getting a few exceptions...

> SEVERE: Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'urlMapping' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tinyMCESpellCheckerWrappingController' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.InstantiationException
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tinyMCESpellCheckerWrappingController' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.InstantiationException

I don't see an error message here so I'm unsure where to begin debugging to determine the cause...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked your other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504548/how-to-integrate-googlespellchecker-with-springmvc-with-servletwrappingcontrolle) and it seems the class TinyMCESpellCheckerServlet is an abstract class which caused this issue on trying instantiating this class.